# How do I text people?

Tags: steins-gate-0

I've been getting texts from people, but I'm not sure how to reply. I know I need to send at least *one* text, to get the [Resonating Reaction Renvoir](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/5402-STEINS;GATE-0/27-Resonating-Reaction-Renvoir) trophy.

I've tried hitting all the buttons I could think of on my controller, but nothing is doing the trick. Does anyone know what button to press?

I know how to access the Rine app on the smartphone, but I can't figure out how to send a message to reply to people. It might be worth mentioning that I haven't figured out how to call people; I have only figured out how to accept/ignore calls so far.

Comment: In the original game(that I played on pc) you need to hover over the different colored words in a text to send a text back. If there are no different colored words you couldn't send a text. Although I'm not sure if it works the same for this one as well.

Comment: @Riley Well it was Suzuka asking me how I was doing, so it seemed like something I should be able to reply to. Unfortunately this one is only for PS4 and Vita, and I have the PS4 version, so hovering isn't an option :/

Comment: I can't find anything on google either. Only thing I can think of is when you have the text open can you click an 'options' field? I vaguely remember there being a field like that, maybe you can reply there.

Comment: @Vemonus deleted my answer as it didn't provide an answer appear to contain information on *how* to respond

Comment: @Wondercricket no worries. My question didn't exactly point that part out, so I added it. It may be that I can't reply to texts yet, but that seems a bit silly. Also the fact that I got a "how are you" text would indicate I should be able to say something back...

Comment: @Vemonus are you far into the game? I remember it being multiple hours until I could reply in the first game.

Comment: @Riley, I have two of the Silver trophies, so I'm guessing I'm at least 2 chapters in? I read there's 14 chapters, if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Vemonus Then that's the problem I assume. At that point I couldn't reply as well.

Comment: @Riley, oh okay, if you can find out the point at which I can start, you should post it as an answer! Thank you for all your help with this :)

Comment: @Vemonus No problem. And I have no idea as I have not played Steins Gate Zero yet, but at the original one it was at chapter 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While finishing my first playthrough (and getting the worst possible ending :( ), I was able to send a few texts.

It appears that you are ***not*** able to respond to all texts that you receive. If you are able to reply, then a pre-written message will already be in the text field on the phone and you are able to shuffle through 3 or so replies with the D-pad before sending one (if you choose to).